# Passing Observable between Component in Angular 4 + RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a code implementation where on button click i have to open a vanilla modal.In this implemetation i have to pass an observable data from the main component to the modal component.Can anyone help and let me know how this can be implemented
In parent component TS file I have an observable:

```
private a = Observable.of({"abc"});
@viewChild('modalID') private modalID: modalComponent;
```

Modal is part of the parent HTML which opens on toggle:

```
<my-modal #modalID> <my-modal>
```

The modal TS wants to access the observable from parent component

Comment: please share what you've implemented

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Input` in your modal and pass it by biding

in your `my-modal`

```
@Input() myObservable: Observable;
```

and then

```
<my-modal [myObservable]="a" #modalID> <my-modal>
```